# Bash: Execute script on file save?

Tags: unit-testing, bash, automation, shell

I'd like to use Bash to run a test suite automatically when I save any file in a given directory.

Is there a mechanism for bash to execute a given script on save events?

Thanks.

::EDIT::

I should have mentioned that I'm on using OSX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edited: you (the OP) mentioned you use OSX. I'm not aware of any similar tools on OSX. There is a low-level system call (inherited from BSD) called "[kqueue](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/kqueue.2.html)", but you'd have to implement your own user-level tool. There is a sample application from Apple, called "[Watcher](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/Watcher/Introduction/Intro.html)", but it's proof of concept only, and doesn't do what you want.

There is [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772209/file-level-filesystem-change-notification-in-mac-os-x) about this on Stack Overflow (also inconclusive).

For lack of an appropriate tool, if you're using a specific programming language, I'd advise you to look for solutions already written for it. Otherwise, I think you're stuck to polling and managing the changes yourself...

Here's my original, Linux-based answer, for archival purposes:

If you're using Linux, you might want to take a look at [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) . More specifically, you can install [inotify-tools](http://wiki.github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/), which include `inotifywait`.

With it, you can monitor files and directories for a number of events, such as access, modification, opening, closing and many others. `inotifywait` can exit once the specified event has been detected, and so a simple loop would get you what you want:

```
while :; do
    inotifywait -e modify /some/directory
    run_test_suite
done
```

By the way, many programming languages and environments already have their own continuous test runners (for instance, with Python you could use [tdaemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tdaemon), among others).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) to detect when a file has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

***Use dnotify only if inotify is not available in Your system (linux kernel < 2.6.13).***

dnotify is standard linux method to watch directories:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnotify

Code example. Watch dir for changes:

```
dnotify WATCH_DIR -M -e SCRIPT_TO_EXECUTE
```

Please note SCRIPT_TO_EXECUTE will be executed every time, when any file in WATCH_DIR changes.

Comment: See [this FAQ](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=inotify&page=faq&lang=en) (fourth question and the page it links to).

Comment: dnotify looks perfect, except I'm on a Mac. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in my post.

Comment: I should second what Dennis pointed to: don't use dnotify, use inotify instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inotify as explained here [Inotify Example: Introduction to Inotify with a C Program Example](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/inotify-c-program-example/)